# Transforming a Query into a View

Tags: sql, oracle, database-view

I have a long query that counts a few itens, based on periods. With that said, I have period P1 (which translates into 07:00:00 and 08:59:59, and so it goes. I have to calculate all the counts by medic and period . I use a binded value to search the table(trunc(a.dt_agenda, 'dd') between :dt_inicial and :dt_final )
Since I use UNION ALL to put all the periods together, the query is quite longs, and I need to store it in a varchar2 field (4000).
So, I need to create an object from my query (probably a view), in a way that in the query searches the view, instead of the table.
Views don't accept binded values and without the bind I can't insert the start date and end date. Anyone has any tip on how I could make this work? Thanks in advance

I've tried creating the view just including the date column in the query, but I wasn't able to make it work after (querying against the view)

```
SELECT

t.medico,
t.periodo, 
t.capacidademaxima, 
t.disponiveis, 
t.usados, 
t.faltas, 
t.cancelamentos, 
t.pa, 
t.reforcopa, 
t.compromissoparicular, 
t.outrosempregos, 
t.reunioeshdp, 
t.reunioeslaboratorios, 
t.almoco,
t.exameseprocedimentos, 
t.hospitaisecirurgias, 
t.aulas, 
t.congresso, 
t.ferias, 
t.maternidade, 
t.tratamentomedico

FROM (
  SELECT 
    obter_desc_agenda(cd_agenda) medico,

    'P1' periodo,

    count(case when a.ie_status_agenda <> 'C' then 1 else null end) capacidademaxima,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) not in (30) and a.ie_status_agenda <> 'C' then 1 else null end) disponiveis,

    count(case when a.ie_status_agenda in ('E','L','N') then 1 else null end) usados,

    count(case when a.ie_status_agenda in ('I') then 1 else null end) faltas,

    count(case when a.ie_status_agenda in ('C') then 1 else null end) cancelamentos,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (10) then 1 else null end) pa,
    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (15) then 1 else null end) reforcopa,
    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (28) then 1 else null end)compromissoparicular,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (12) then 1 else null end) outrosempregos,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (16) then 1 else null end) reunioeshdp,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (26) then 1 else null end) reunioeslaboratorios,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (20) then 1 else null end) ferias,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (33) then 1 else null end) almoco,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (27) then 1 else null end) exameseprocedimentos,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (11) then 1 else null end) hospitaisecirurgias,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (13) then 1 else null end) aulas,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (14) then 1 else null end) congresso,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (32) then 1 else null end) tratamentomedico,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (31) then 1 else null end) maternidade

FROM
    agenda_consulta a 
WHERE
    trunc(a.dt_agenda, 'dd') between :dt_inicial and :dt_final 
    AND to_char(a.dt_agenda, 'HH24:MI:SS') between ('07:00:00') and ('08:59:59')
GROUP BY
    obter_desc_agenda(cd_agenda), 'P1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    obter_desc_agenda(cd_agenda) medico,

    'P2' periodo,

    count(case when a.ie_status_agenda <> 'C' then 1 else null end) capacidademaxima,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) not in (30) and a.ie_status_agenda <> 'C' then 1 else null end) disponiveis,

    count(case when a.ie_status_agenda in ('E','L','N') then 1 else null end) usados,

    count(case when a.ie_status_agenda in ('I') then 1 else null end) faltas,

    count(case when a.ie_status_agenda in ('C') then 1 else null end) cancelamentos,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (10) then 1 else null end) pa,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (15) then 1 else null end) reforcopa,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (28) then 1 else null end)compromissoparicular,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (12) then 1 else null end) outrosempregos,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (16) then 1 else null end) reunioeshdp,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (26) then 1 else null end) reunioeslaboratorios,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (20) then 1 else null end) ferias,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (33) then 1 else null end) almoco,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (27) then 1 else null end) exameseprocedimentos,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (11) then 1 else null end) hospitaisecirurgias,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (13) then 1 else null end) aulas,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (14) then 1 else null end) congresso,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (32) then 1 else null end) tratamentomedico,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (31) then 1 else null end) maternidade
FROM
    agenda_consulta a 
WHERE trunc(a.dt_agenda, 'dd') between :dt_inicial and :dt_final  
    AND to_char (a.dt_agenda, 'HH24:MI:SS') between ('09:00:00') and ('11:59:59')
GROUP BY obter_desc_agenda(cd_agenda), 'P2'

UNION ALL
```

`Then it repeats to P3, P4, P5 and the last part is "Total"`

```
SELECT 

    obter_desc_agenda(cd_agenda) medico,

    'Total' periodo, 

    count(case when a.ie_status_agenda <> 'C' then 1 else null end) capacidademaxima,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) not in (30) and a.ie_status_agenda <> 'C' then 1 else null end) disponiveis,

    count(case when a.ie_status_agenda in ('E','L','N') then 1 else null end) usados,

    count(case when a.ie_status_agenda in ('I') then 1 else null end) faltas,

    count(case when a.ie_status_agenda in ('C') then 1 else null end) cancelamentos,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (10) then 1 else null end) pa,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (15) then 1 else null end) reforcopa,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (28) then 1 else null end)compromissoparicular,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (12) then 1 else null end) outrosempregos,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (16) then 1 else null end) reunioeshdp,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (26) then 1 else null end) reunioeslaboratorios,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (20) then 1 else null end) ferias,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (33) then 1 else null end) almoco,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (27) then 1 else null end) exameseprocedimentos,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (11) then 1 else null end) hospitaisecirurgias,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (13) then 1 else null end) aulas,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (14) then 1 else null end) congresso,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (32) then 1 else null end) tratamentomedico,

    count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (31) then 1 else null end) maternidade

FROM
agenda_consulta a 

WHERE trunc(a.dt_agenda, 'dd') between :dt_inicial and :dt_final 

GROUP BY
    obter_desc_agenda(cd_agenda), 'Total'

) t

order by medico, periodo
```

Comment: Are  :dt_inicial and :dt_final somehow relative to sysdate ? Could you just write trunc(a.dt_agenda, 'dd') between sysdate-2 and sysdate  ?

Comment: No, unfortunately they are not sysdate related. The values may change anytime like :startdate and :finaldate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create view from this select :

```
SELECT 
    obter_desc_agenda(cd_agenda) medico,
    case 
      when to_char(a.dt_agenda, 'HH24:MI:SS') between ('07:00:00') and ('08:59:59') then 'P1'
      when to_char(a.dt_agenda, 'HH24:MI:SS') between ('09:00:00') and ('11:59:59') then 'P2'
      when to_char(a.dt_agenda, 'HH24:MI:SS') between ('12:00:00') and ('14:59:59') then 'P3'
      when to_char(a.dt_agenda, 'HH24:MI:SS') between ('15:00:00') and ('16:59:59') then 'P4'
      when to_char(a.dt_agenda, 'HH24:MI:SS') between ('17:00:00') and ('19:59:59') then 'P5'
    end periodo,
    trunc(a.dt_agenda, 'dd') date_agenda,
    case when a.ie_status_agenda <> 'C' then 1 else null end capacidademaxima, -- don't count yet - only set flags (1 or null)
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) not in (30) and a.ie_status_agenda <> 'C' then 1 else null end disponiveis,
    case when a.ie_status_agenda in ('E','L','N') then 1 else null end usados,
    case when a.ie_status_agenda in ('I') then 1 else null end faltas,
    case when a.ie_status_agenda in ('C') then 1 else null end cancelamentos,
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (10) then 1 else null end pa,
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (15) then 1 else null end reforcopa,
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (28) then 1 else null end compromissoparicular,
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (12) then 1 else null end outrosempregos,
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (16) then 1 else null end reunioeshdp,
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (26) then 1 else null end reunioeslaboratorios,
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (20) then 1 else null end ferias,
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (33) then 1 else null end almoco,
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (27) then 1 else null end exameseprocedimentos,
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (11) then 1 else null end hospitaisecirurgias,
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (13) then 1 else null end aulas,
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (14) then 1 else null end congresso,
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (32) then 1 else null end tratamentomedico,
    case when nvl(a.nr_seq_motivo_transf,0) in (31) then 1 else null end maternidade
    from agenda_consulta a
```

and use it like this:

```
select medico, nvl(periodo, 'Total') -- nvl is there because grouping only by medico(counting Total) gives null in periodo
     , count(capacidademaxima)
     , count(disponiveis)
     , count(usados)
     ...
     , count(tratamentomedico)
     , count(maternidade)
  from viewName
 where date_agenda between :dt_inicial and :dt_final 
 group by grouping sets((periodo, medico), (medico)) -- it's the same as doing group by periodo, medico (counts groups P1 to P5) union all group by medico (counts Total)
```

Comment: God you are a genious. I had the job done, but with a way more complex solution.  I've made a function to return a table... `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE REL_HORARIOS_type
AS OBJECT
(
   medico VARCHAR2(1000),
   periodo VARCHAR2(100),...` Then `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE REL_HORARIOS_table_type
AS TABLE OF REL_HORARIOS_type;....` Then... `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION HORARIOSDISPONIVEIS(dt_inicial DATE, dt_final DATE)
RETURN REL_HORARIOS_table_type
PIPELINED
AS
BEGIN
   FOR v_Rec IN (SELECT ....`

Answer (score 0):

Take `trunc(a.dt_agenda, 'dd')` to `SELECT-list` and `GROUP BY-list` and `CREATE VIEW` as below :

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] VIEW v_agenda_consulta AS
SELECT trunc(a.dt_agenda, 'dd') as dt_agenda, 'P1' as periodo, count( case when ....
  FROM agenda_consulta a 
 WHERE to_char(a.dt_agenda, 'HH24:MI:SS') between ('07:00:00') and ('08:59:59')
 GROUP BY trunc(a.dt_agenda, 'dd'), obter_desc_agenda(cd_agenda), 'P1'
UNION ALL
SELECT trunc(a.dt_agenda, 'dd'), 'P2' , count( case when ....
  FROM agenda_consulta a 
 WHERE to_char(a.dt_agenda, 'HH24:MI:SS') between ('07:00:00') and ('08:59:59')
 GROUP BY trunc(a.dt_agenda, 'dd'), obter_desc_agenda(cd_agenda), 'P2'
UNION ALL
SELECT trunc(a.dt_agenda, 'dd'), 'Total' , count( case when ....
  FROM agenda_consulta a 
 WHERE to_char(a.dt_agenda, 'HH24:MI:SS') between ('07:00:00') and ('08:59:59')
 GROUP BY trunc(a.dt_agenda, 'dd'), obter_desc_agenda(cd_agenda), 'Total';
```

And you can call as

```
SELECT *
  FROM v_agenda_consulta 
 WHERE dt_agenda between :dt_inicial and :dt_final
```

*Pay attention in the first try to create use `CREATE VIEW v_agenda_consulta AS ...` without `REPLACE` option. You might have an existing `VIEW` to be overridden.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I can't group by date, since it'll make the "Periods" repeat for each date, that's why I tried to place the date in a subquery. As you can see in the two images, the one above is date grouped, and the second one is not(which is my desired result) . https://photos.app.goo.gl/vcY3q34qiVkY4nmp8

Comment: And if I try to put the date in a subquery, like this: SELECT obter_desc_agenda(cd_agenda) medico, (select trunc(dt_agenda, 'dd') from agenda_consulta) as dt_agenda, 'P1' as periodo,
      and then removing from the GROUP BY, I get an error while trying to query the view. For example: SELECT *
  FROM HORARIOSDISPONIVEIS 
 WHERE dt_agenda between :dt_inicial and :dt_final .... That returns ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: It returns `ORA-01427` because you have no `where` clause in `(select trunc(dt_agenda, 'dd') from agenda_consulta)` so it tries to select every dt_agenda in the table.